# Cycle in type synonym declarations

Tags: haskell, types

I want to try out Haskell `type` and `data` with the following code

```
type Program a = Maybe a -> (Operation a, Maybe Program a)
data Operation a = Read a | Write a
```

`Program` follows a continuation passing style (CPS) and `Nothing` indicates termination. `a` may be instantiated with `Int` or something else.

However, GHC complains that:

```
main.hs:1:1:
    Cycle in type synonym declarations:
      main.hs:1:1-58: type Program a =
                          Maybe a -> (Operation a, Maybe Program a)
```

I'm new to Haskell so I don't understand why this is not allowed. How can I express this type in Haskell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- it should be `Maybe (Program a)`, not `Maybe Program a`
- type synonyms cannot be recursive

A working version would be:

```
newtype Program a = Program { runProgram :: Maybe a -> (Operation a, Maybe (Program a)) }
data Operation a = Read a | Write a
```

Comment: Thanks. If I use this `newtype` and `runProgram`, could you pls show me how to call the function?

Comment: `f :: Program a -> Maybe a -> (Operation a, Maybe (Program a))`;
`f p m = (runProgram p) m` -- `runProgram` is record field, so it can be called like ordinary function.